# Building a product-filter in NodeJS/MongoDB: only works when selecting all filters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am building a product-filter in nodeJS. It works when i **hard-code** the following find()

```
 const products = await Product.find({
            price: {
              $gte: price[0],
              $lte: price[1],
            }, category: categories, shipping: shipping})
```

The problem is of course that it only gives result if entered all the search options in the front-end.
However i also want the filter to work if i choose to **NOT** enter all the search options.
Thus i came up with the following code, to store all filters in an array, but it doesn't give any results.
**The output of the array is =**

```
  { price: { '$gte': 0, '$lte': 40820 } },
  {
    category: [
      '60657e1d328b25043581e46f',
      '601ef1ea8e06fc04cdaa5080',
      '601eeaeb8e06fc04cdaa507f'
    ]
  },
  { shipping: 'Yes' }
] <<<_--- content of searchArry????
```

**This is my code, but it returns no results** =

```
exports.searchFilters = async (req, res) => {
  try {
  const categories = req.body.categoryIds;
  const price = req.body.price; 
  const shipping = req.body.shipping;
  console.log(price, "<<<------- price data received in backend???"); 
  console.log(categories, "<<--- categories data received in backend???"); 
  console.log(shipping, "<<---- shipping data received in backend"); 
  
  const searchArray = [];
 
  if (req.body.price) {
    const price = {
      $gte: req.body.price[0],
      $lte: req.body.price[1],
    }
    searchArray.push({ "price" : price });
  }

  if (req.body.categoryIds) {
    

    searchArray.push({ "category" : categories });
  }

  if (req.body.shipping) {
    
    searchArray.push({ "shipping" : shipping });
  }

        console.log(searchArray, "<<<_--- content of searchArry????");

  const products = await Product.find({searchArray})
  .populate("category", "_id name") 
  .populate("subs", "_id name") 
  .populate("postedBy", "_id name") 
  .exec(); 
  
  res.json(products);
  // console.log(products, "<<--producte?? ") console.log(products.length, "<<--- lengte") } catch(err) { console.log(err); }}
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hardcoded call looks like this:

```
Product.find({price, category, shipping}) // the arg is an object
```

And the second call (with `searchArray`) looks like:

```
Product.find({searchArray: [{price}, {category}, {shipping}]}) // the arg is an object containing an array of objects
```

**Try merging the elements of `searchArray` into a single object:**

```
Product.find(Object.assign({}, ...searchArray))
```

---

*Note: Be aware that `{variableName}` is a shorthand for `{variableName: variableName}` or `{"variableName": variableName}`.*